# How can i parse MIDIRawData (SysEx) out of a midiEvent in Swift 3? (under iOS)

Tags: ios, coremidi

i have big trouble parsing `MIDIRawData` (SysEx Data) out of a midi-event of a MusicTrack (XCode8.1, iOS10.1)
I managed to parse `MidiNoteMessages` and `MidiChannelMessages` with the following code (Swift3):

(eventType and eventData was extracted with MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo…)

```
switch eventType {

case kMusicEventType_MIDINoteMessage:

     let temp = eventData?.bindMemory(to: MIDINoteMessage.self, capacity: 5)
     let channel = temp!.pointee.channel
     let note = temp!.pointee.note 
     let vel = temp!.pointee.velocity
     let relVel = temp!.pointee.releaseVelocity
     let duration = temp!.pointee.duration

case kMusicEventType_MIDIChannelMessage:
     let temp = eventData?.bindMemory(to: MIDIChannelMessage.self, capacity: 4)
     let status = temp!.pointee.status & 0b11110000
     let channel = temp!.pointee.status & 0b0000111
     let data1 = temp!.pointee.data1
     let data2 = temp!.pointee.data2
     let reserved = temp!.pointee.reserved
```

In the following case i get the right length of the data, but data itself just consists of the first entry of the SysEx Message

```
case kMusicEventType_MIDIRawData:
                debug.printDebugText(text: "kMusicEventType_MIDIRawData", ToConsole: debugViewGlobal)
     let raw = eventData?.bindMemory(to: MIDIRawData.self, capacity: 2)
     let length = raw!.pointee.length
     let data = raw!.pointee.data // (should be of Type (UInt8)… but is just one UInt8 Value
```

How can i get the rest of the SysEs Message ?
How do i have to handle (UInt8) ?

Thank You,
Sebastian